# AS3 / AIR : How to make a dynamic text clickable (to load a saved progress)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

**Where to start...**

I want to make a list of users in an Android application (in a dynamic txt box). When the user clicks their name as shown on the list, a button will appear so that his/her previous progress will be loaded. This is a Flash/AIR using Actionscript 3 code.

Comment: Normally this would be closed for being not a real **technical** / **programming** Question. Show code of **what you've tried** for each part. Being a programmer (_ie: make `tool X` to solve `problem Y`_) means doing some research to solve each task...

Answer (score 1):

A broad question, but I'll offer some suggestions as a starting point.

You might consider [Feathers](https://feathersui.com/) for your UI components (clickable user names) and assuming user progress only needs to be saved to the local device, the [Encrypted Local Store](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e31.html) can be used as a simple means to locally store/save user progress.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Would you mind if I send to you my sourcefile? And let's exchange emails. Thanks!

Comment: The original question does not allow people to provide specific assistance so perhaps try some things, see what works, or doesn't, or needs clarification and if necessary, post a new, more specific question if you run into difficulty.  Feel free to share a code snippet from what you've tried, with your new question, too.